# MOXy ignores XmlElement(required=true)

Tags: xml, unmarshalling, moxy

I have the following POJOs:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DataList<T>
{
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="ResultTableSection")
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    public List<T> elements;
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "ResultTable")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Event
{
    @XmlElement(name = "TSSEVENTID", required = true)
    public Integer id;
    ...
}
```

When in the response XML **TSSEVENTID** tag is missing I get a DataList in which Event.id field is NULL regardless of the set required=true. Nothing fails.
Is it the expected behavior ? How can I enable validation ?

Unmarshall code:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(DataList.class, Hall.class).createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(xmlDocument);
```

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [JAXB (JSR-222)](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation is not expected to throw an exception or `ValidationEvent` if a required element is missing.  The `required` flag on `@XmlElement` only impacts how an XML Schema is generated.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html#required%28%29

**Demo**

In the demo code below I have specified a `ValidationEventHandler` on the `Unmarshaller` to catch any exceptions.  Running this code with either MOXy or the JAXB reference implementation won't result in any exceptions being thrown.

```java
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(DataList.class, Event.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

        unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new ValidationEventHandler() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
                System.out.println(event.getMessage());
                return false;
            }
        });

        File xml = new File("src/forum21593351/input.xml");
        DataList dl = (DataList) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(dl, System.out);

    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <ResultTableSection>
        <ResultTable>
        </ResultTable>
    </ResultTableSection>
</Root>
```

### Enabling Validation

> How can I enable validation ?

You can set an instance of `Schema` on your `Unmarshaller` to have the input validated.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html

Comment: Thanks for valuable answer. This is a thirdparty data for which they don't provide a schema, so of course your words sound reasonable. Why should I be placing my own expectations ?